# How do you decode GraphQL::Schema::UniqueWithinType in Postgres?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, graphql

Say someone evil stored an encoded id in your database and you needed to use it. Example:

Ruby:

```
GraphQL::Schema::UniqueWithinType.default_id_separator = '|'
relay_id = GraphQL::Schema::UniqueWithinType.encode('User', '123')
# "VXNlcnwxMjM="
```

How do I get `123` out of `VXNlcnwxMjM=` in Postgres?

Answer (score 0):

Ruby:

```
GraphQL::Schema::UniqueWithinType.default_id_separator = '|'
relay_id = GraphQL::Schema::UniqueWithinType.encode('User', '123')
# "VXNlcnwxMjM="
Base64.decode64(relay_id)
# "User|123"
```

To get "123" out of "VXNlcnwxMjM=" in Postgres SQL you can do this horror show

```
select  
    substring(
        (decode('VXNlcnwxMjM=', 'base64')::text)
        from (char_length('User|') + 1)
        for (char_length(decode('VXNlcnwxMjM=', 'base64')::text) - char_length('User|'))
    )::int
```

Edit: Playing around with this ... on Postgres 9.6.5 the above works... but our staging server is 10.5 and I had to do this instead (which also works on 9.6.5)

```
select  
    substring(
        convert_from(decode('VXNlcnwxMjM=', 'base64'), 'UTF-8')
        from (char_length('User|') + 1)
        for (char_length(convert_from(decode('VXNlcnwxMjM=', 'base64'), 'UTF-8')) - char_length('User|'))
    )::int
```